# ExtJS: How to get the width of a button before it's added?

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

Is there a way to get the width of button before its added to the panel in a situation such as follows:

```
var myButton = Ext.widget('button', {
       text : 'Hello'
});

myButton.getWidth(); //This is undefined

panel.add(myButton);
```

I know that since the button is't rendered on screen and I haven't explicitly given it a width, there is no way to know the width at this time. But is there an event or something else just before the button is rendered that will let me know its width before it's displayed on screen ?

Comment: You can get a width of an element if it's hidden. So you can append the button in HTML and then get it's width.

Comment: @Jenna: Can you plz specify why you require width of button before render, bcoz at any case you will not get button width until it is rendered.We can help u if u specify you requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can't, if you have a look to the button source code his dimensions are setted on his render.

You shouldn't work with the button width, instead you should use other layouts.

Probably there is a way, but it seems crazy:

```
var myButton = Ext.widget('button', {
       text : 'Hello'
}),
clone=Ext.clone(myButton);
panel.add(clone);
clone.getWidth();//This is width
clone.destroy();

panel.add(myButton);
```

Like you can see the problem is on creating and adding it to only get his width.
It has probably no sense, but if you need to do something else change the question with something more clear. And surely we can get an answer to your problem.